# Ошибка: min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

"Напишите функцию, которая будет принимать имя файла и возвращать кортеж из четырех чисел: минимум и максимум первой координаты, минимум и максимум второй координаты."
Пример ввода:

```
1 2
3 4
-2 23
3 -1
```

Требуемый вывод:

```
(-2, 3, -1, 23)
```

Неудачная попытка:

```
def minmax_coords(filename):
    newlist = []
    coordinates1 = []
    coordinates2 = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i in f:
            newlist.append(i)
        for j in range(len(newlist)):
            if j % 2 == 0:
                coordinates1.append(j)
            else:
                coordinates2.append(j)
    if len(newlist):
        return min(coordinates1), max(coordinates1), min(coordinates2), max(coordinates2)
    return None, None, None, None
```

Почему аргумент остается пустой, если есть условие для списка, длина которого равна нулю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое: когда вы разбиваете файл на строки, вы не разбиваете строки на символы по пробелу, следовательно в список "аппендите" целые строки с символами переноса строки `\n` (попробуйте распечатать ваш `newlist` после того как его собрали, чтобы посмотреть как он выглядит)
Второе: в цикле, когда разбиваете список на х и у координаты, вы в ваши списки добавляете не элементы по индексу, а индексы элементов.

Вот так будет правильно:

```
def minmax_coords(filename):
    newlist = []
    coordinates1 = []
    coordinates2 = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i in f:
            for j in i.split():
                newlist.append(j)
        for j in range(len(newlist)):
            if j % 2 == 0:
                coordinates1.append(int(newlist[j]))
            else:
                coordinates2.append(int(newlist[j]))
    if len(newlist):
        return min(coordinates1), max(coordinates1), min(coordinates2), max(coordinates2)
    return None, None, None, None
```